# How to undo an accidental change in a project task list (SharePoint 2019)?

Tags: sharepoint-server, tasks, task-list, project-server, pwa

How can I undo changes made to a task title and restore previous text in a project task list (PWA app on SharePoint 2019), when there is no **undo** button and **ctrl+z** doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the versioning of the item and restore an oder version, where the title is still correct. Of course this would turn other changes made to the task oboslete as well. Here is what to do. I assume you use the modern list view.

Open the context menu of the item (three vertical dots shown near the name) and navigate to "Version history":
[image: SharePoint item context menu]

An overlay will open with the versions, changes, date and author:
[image: Version history overlay]

Klick the small arrow beside the Date and chose "Restore"
[image: Restore item]